# Add a date picker to a JetStrap page (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, jetstrap

*Just* started using JetStrap tonight to build some very basic entry forms. Lots of cool tools and fields, but no date picker. ([Check it out if you haven't!](https://www.jetstrap.com/)) Other topics discuss this being done with Twitter Bootstrap, but not very directly...

Can I extend the libraries / controls available in the JetStrap page by pulling in from other web sources (a Google hosted library for example) to add in additional functionality? I'm very new to web front end work and would like to do as much work in JetStrap as possible without having to download the code locally and set up my own local IIS site.

Comment: Since you specified if *you* can extend what is available in JetStrap, probably not, which is unfortunate because it all around looks like a good tool. It looks like a closed system though. Perhaps if enough people sent in support requests, they would add it.

Comment: That is my suspicion. I just keep *hoping* that someone else will have the secret magic...

Comment: Haven't used JetStrap yet. If you can edit the JS you can probably use jQuery $.getScript() like this datepicker example on Bootply http://bootply.com/60791

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am one of the creators of Jetstrap.

We will be adding an easy external JS/CSS feature very soon, but in the mean time, you can load the script dynamically with javascript in the JS editor:

```
$(function() {
    $.getScript('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.0.2/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js', function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
})
```

And in the markup you can add:

```
<input type="text" value="02-16-2012" class="datepicker">
```