# Reference JQuery in JetStrap (Online Twitter Bootstrap Editor)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jetstrap

I would like to pull in and use JQuery functions inside of the JetStrap editor (it is an online twitter bootstrap editor).

This code was [given to me earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661440/add-a-date-picker-to-a-jetstrap-page-twitter-bootstrap) for referencing a single function:

```
$(function() {
    $.getScript('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.0.2/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js', function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
})
```

Can I recycle this code to reference the Google hosted version of JQuery so that I can use all its built in functions? Do I have to reference functions one at a time? Green to both JetStrap and web front end development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think JetStrap includes jQuery for you so that any code you put in the JS editor can use jQuery and any components in the bootstrap.js

When you render in 'Test' mode, and then view source you'll see these are included..

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/jetstrap-site/lib/bootstrap/2.3.0/js/bootstrap.js">
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I should have thought to check there... Just getting started with all this.

Comment: Yep. jQuery is included by default. We will make it easy to add external files soon beyond using things like getScript or creating script nodes.